# TKlib problem while loading in wish when trying to maintain a wish and freewrap-able environment

Tags: package, tcl

I seem to have a very simple problem, but I can't get a grip on it. Befor coming to the code, I must post some assumtions, under what conditions it should run:
To be able to create .exe files with FreeWrap (6.75) seamless, we created a Networkpath, that holds all the libs, that are included in Freewrap itself, all the same versions. Then we have another patch, where all the Libs reside, we would need in our applications. Freewrap then gets access to the latter path, our wish is given access to *both* paths. The goal is, to provide both systems (wish and Freewrap) the very same library set, to ensure, that developing with wish creates the same results with Freewrap.

Now the problem: This all works as expected, with one exception. That is the Tklib07. What happens:
Any library, even heavy stuff like twapi, gets loaded correctly in wish and the Freewrap .exe. But if I place a

```
     package req tablelist
```

I receive errors like "tk_nextfokus" or "tablelist::common" mismatch or missing when starting in *wish* (!). The Exe Version works.

After a bit of research we found out, that the ...strange pkgindex.tcl of tklib07 seems to not provide the depending packages in itself in a block, but tries to load the "tablelist" source in it anyway, which leads to the missing dependencies.
If I now execute the pkgindex.tcl content in the console and try "package req tablelist" right after, anything runs fine. But it obviously should work without this hassle. What am I missing, or what other way is, to enforce the load of Tklib07 before loading any other stuff?

Still under the assumtion to the very limited Library-Paths for both System (wish and Freewrap), here a small sample of the code that for us should feed the needs for both:

```
      if {[namespace exists ::freewrap]} {
        set auto_path [list]
        foreach fpath [zvfs::list */tmp/*/pkgIndex.tcl] {
            lappend auto_path [file dirname $fpath]
        }
        foreach fpath [zvfs::list */*/pkgIndex.tcl] {
            lappend auto_path [file dirname $fpath]
        }
      } else {
        # the wish auto_path.......
        set auto_path [list]
        lappend auto_path "c:/freewrap/innerlib"
        lappend auto_path "c:/freewrap/outerlib"
      }

      console show
      foreach p $auto_path {
        puts $p
      }
      
      package req Tcl
      package req Tk
      tk_messageBox -message "Stop"
      package req tablelist
      
      package req twapi
      package req cffi
      package req tdbc
      package req Thread
      package req sqlite3
      
      puts Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution by ... trial and error.

If you repeat the foreach steps for the innerlib and outerlib directories in the "else" part (for wish), using globs instead of the zvfs::list command, searching for all pkgindex.tcl in those dirs and put them in auto_path as well, all works correctly.

For the time beeing, this is our current workaround.
But nevertheless, this all should not be necessary, usually whish does it on its own. We're all aware of that, so it seems, some internal aspect is not triggered right. Would be nice to know, what it is, to do it right :)